# Adding a segue between Imageview and Viewcontroller in Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have a viewcontroller which consists of couple of icons in it.  I need a add a segue between the image and another Table View controller. Currently I am not able a add a segue in storyboard?

Any help

Comment: You should use UIButton with background image instead of UIImageView.

Comment: why do you need to add segue b/w image and tableview controller ? what's your goal ?

Comment: On clicking a particular image icon, The app should move to another TableViewcontroller.

Comment: u were added the gesture method, or it is the single image

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik It is a single image..

Answer (score 1):

Create a segue from ViewController to the destination controller, and add a tap gesture recognizer to uiimageview. On this tap recognizer just performSegueWithIdentifier

Answer (score 1):

Instead of connecting and creating segue from individual cells, you can connect all those segues from the View Controller button, lying below your view in your storyboard. In this case, you will have multiple segues and none of them will be individually connected to cells. And when segues are ready, you can use this method for moving on to the next View Controller depending on which cell is tapped from the tableView.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegue" sender:nil];
```

You just have to check which cell is tapped and then perform the appropriate Segue on tap.

Look out for the yellow button as shown below your View Screen in your storyboard.

[image]

Drag and drop a segue from that button onto the View Controller that you want to connect.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a button and provide a image as per you need and then add segue b/w it and tableview controller as below :-

[image: UIButton and TableViewController]

This will work for you.